# Android Room fails to validate schema: all tables disappeared

Tags: android, android-room

I've added room to my app and everything seemed to work fine until I pushed another release of the app with NO changes in database schema: some users experience crashes during database

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: users(com.iproxy.application.data.room.UserEntity).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='users', columns={last_name=Column{name='last_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, first_name=Column{name='first_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, email=Column{name='email', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='users', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
       at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:163)
       at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:135)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:195)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:428)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:313)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:324)
       at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
       at com.iproxy.application.data.room.UsersDao_Impl$14.call(UsersDao_Impl.java:378)
       at com.iproxy.application.data.room.UsersDao_Impl$14.call(UsersDao_Impl.java:375)
       at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.java:54)
...
```

I do not have prepackaged database in my project. So, it seems as if all user has the db file but it is empty.

I cannot find the cause of this. But it seems to affect around 5% of users, which is a lot. If anyone here faced similar issue or has any idea what could be the cause, I would really appreciate if you share it.

**UPDATE**
Database is created in dagger as singleton:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideDatabase(context: Application, legacyMigration: LegacyDataMigration): AppDatabase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "main.db")
        .setQueryExecutor(Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor())
        .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                try {
                    db.beginTransaction()
                    legacyMigration.migrateData(db, delete = false)
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful()
                } catch (error: Exception) {
                    Timber.tag("DB").e(error, "Failed to pre-populate database")
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction()
                }
            }
        })
        .build()
}
```

Because I was migrating from shared preferences, I had to add special migration logic for when the database is created for the first time.
`legacyMigration.migrateData(db)` just copies data from shared preferences in transaction.

Here is my database declaration:

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        UserEntity::class,
        UserSettingEntity::class,
        ConnectionEntity::class,
        ConnectionSettingEntity::class,
        IpHistoryEntity::class,
        AppSettingEntity::class,
    ],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val usersDao: UsersDao

    abstract val connectionsDao: ConnectionsDao

    abstract val connectionSettingsDao: ConnectionSettingsDao

    abstract val userSettingsDao: UserSettingsDao

    abstract val ipHistoryDao: IpHistoryDao

    abstract val appSettingsDao: AppSettingsDao

}
```

I will list only 2 entities here, let me know if you need more

```
@Entity(tableName = "app_settings")
data class AppSettingEntity(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "key")
    val key: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "value")
    val value: String? = null
)

@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class UserEntity(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "email")
    val email: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    val firstName: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    val lastName: String? = null
)
```

The problem happens during database open when I try to call `UsersDao.getCurrentUser()` where I have a problem is here:

```
@Dao
interface UsersDao {

    @Query("select * from users where id = :userId")
    suspend fun findById(userId: String): UserEntity?

    @Query("select * from users where id = :userId")
    fun observeUserById(userId: String): Flow<UserEntity?>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    suspend fun insert(user: UserEntity)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertOrReplace(user: UserEntity)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(user: UserEntity): Int

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(user: UserEntity)

    @Query("delete from users where id = :userId")
    suspend fun deleteById(userId: String)

    @Query(
        """
        select u.* from users as u, app_settings as s
        where s.`key` = '${AppSettingKey.KEY_CURRENT_USER_ID}' and s.value = u.id
    """
    )
    suspend fun getCurrentUser(): UserEntity?

    @Query(
        """
        select u.* from users as u, app_settings as s
        where s.`key` = '${AppSettingKey.KEY_CURRENT_USER_ID}' and s.value = u.id
    """
    )
    fun observeCurrentUser(): Flow<UserEntity?>
}
```

Comment: Please show your Room code: the Daos and Entities, especially.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added the code. Could it be a problem that db is opened from 2 different processes? However, none of my components run in a separate process...